# How to make a super in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like in this example:

```
var teste = {name:'marcos'};
$(teste).each(function(){

    var name = this.name; // i don't want to do that.

    // i want to have access to 'this' inside this function (sayName)
    var sayName = function(){
        alert(name); // there is something like "super" in java? or similar way to do?
    }
    sayName();

});
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

`this` is never implicit in JavaScript (as it is in Java). This means that if you do not invoke a function as a method on an object, `this` will not be bound to something reasonable (it will be bound to the `window` object in the browser).
If you want to have a `this` inside the function, that function should be used as a method, that is:

```
var teste = {name:'marcos'};
$(teste).each(function(){

    this.sayName = function(){
        alert(this.name); 
    }
    this.sayName();

});
```

Then sayName is a method and is invoked in `this`

Comment: you can safely remove `var name = ...` and replace `alert(name)` with `alert(this.name)`, I believe this was original intention. Besides, it adds `sayName` to `test` object and next `each` will count `sayName` too, which is not good.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Try it, it works. `this` inside function while calling `this.sayName()` is the same as otside, i.e. `teste` object.

Comment: @Victor: In your highly-localised example. Not for this pattern in general.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a lot of examples on Internet (jQuery-based including) using this:

```
var that = this;
var sayName = function() {
   alert(that.name);
}
```

Comment: -1: This is the OP's original code. He's asking for an alternative to this.

Comment: This is unfair and wrong. He asked: "i want to have access to 'this' inside this function"

Comment: And in the line above that, he demonstrates your solution and writes "i don't want to do that"

Comment: I believe he said "I don't want to do 'name = this.name'". Not all people knows you can store "this" into a variable, and it's unfair to give me -1 for that.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that he was looking for something a little more exotic than setting a variable. Sorry if you feel otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

Here is yet another way:

```
var teste = {name:'marcos'};
$(teste).each(function(){

var that = this;

var sayName = function(){
    alert(that.name);
}
sayName();

});
```

That is your super :-)
Seriously, there is no "super" because it's not extension.

Comment: -1: This is the OP's original code. He's asking for an alternative to this.